# jQuery animate callback firing twice in Firefox and sometimes in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-callback

I have the following code:

```
$logo.css({
    top : '800px'
}).animate({
    top : '200px'
}, 2000, function() {
    $text.animate({
        height : '800px'
    }, 2000, function() {
        console.log("this fires twice in firefox, and sometimes in chrome too");
    });
    console.log("this fires twice in firefox, and sometimes in chrome too");
});
```

In IE - it's consistently firing both callback functions once, just like I want it to.

In Firefox - it's consistently firing both callback functions twice.

In Chrome - it's sometimes firing functions once, and sometimes twice.

QUESTION - How to fix it so that both callback functions are called just once?

Comment: What's the `.length` of `$text` and `$logo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `.stop(true)` before each `.animate()`

If that doesn't help , do it with `.stop(true,true)` instead.

```
$logo.css({
    top : '800px'
}).stop(true).animate({
    top : '200px'
}, 2000, function() {
    $text.stop(true).animate({
        height : '800px'
    }, 2000, function() {
        console.log("this fires twice in firefox, and sometimes in chrome too");
    });
    console.log("this fires twice in firefox, and sometimes in chrome too");
});
```